# SQL Server update returns the wrong value

Tags: sql-server

I have an update query which is returning an incorrect result.

```
UPDATE StagingWarehouse.dbo.BusinessLeads
SET    CompanyFK = c.CustomerPK
FROM   StagingWarehouse.dbo.BusinessLeads s
       INNER JOIN DataWarehouse.dim.Customer c
         ON c.CustomerBK = s.CompanyBK
WHERE  s.businessleadbk = 5796722
```

When selecting `businessleadbk = 5796722` from the `StagingWarehouse.dbo.BusinessLeads` after running this statement the `CompanyFK` is set to 11024703. The problem being is that `CustomerPK` 11024703 on `DataWarehouse.dim.Customer` does not exist and running the below query returns no results, so I have no idea where it's getting that number from.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   StagingWarehouse.dbo.BusinessLeads s
       INNER JOIN DataWarehouse.dim.Customer c
         ON c.CustomerBK = s.CompanyBK
WHERE  s.businessleadbk = 5796722
```

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the value it had pre update? If no rows match then no update will happen.

Comment: No i even reset it to 0 and ran it again. When it first get entered into that table it has no value until the update statement. Out of several million rows there is only one that is causing issue.

Comment: Are you able to upload the actual execution plan XML for both the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT`?

Comment: how do I upload them here?

Comment: You would need to upload to pastebin or similar.

Comment: select statement http://pastebin.com/2ZYsdXqX

Comment: update statement http://pastebin.com/9aC9xuRj

Comment: That's interesting. The `SELECT` plan returns a row from `[Customer].[CustomerBK]` that later gets eliminated when it tries to do a key lookup on `[Customer].[PK__Customer__A4AFAF8865B6F546]` and can't find a matching row. The `UPDATE` statement doesn't need the key lookup so the row is never eliminated. I'd check the table for corruption. If you change the `SELECT` list to `SELECT c.CustomerPK` instead of `SELECT c.*` I presume you now get a row returned?

Comment: Yes i get the result if i change it to SELECT c.CustomerPK. Running corruption check now

Comment: Yes the table shows corruption. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` plan is shown below

[image: Update]

All of the operators in the plan have 1 row emitted.

The `SELECT` plan is

[image: Select]

Somehow the row disappears after it has already been found in the `CustomerBK` index on `Customer` whilst SQL Server tries to look up the corresponding PK in the clustered index on the same table. This would indicate some sort of corruption. Perhaps the NCI has an additional row compared with the CI or somehow the PK value stored in the NCI is invalid.

I'd run [`DBCC CHECKTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174338.aspx)